# Python: import by relative path gives an error

Tags: python

I try to import a variable from another module by relative import path. Alas, is gives me an error:

```
C:\Python35\python.exe D:/Projects/baka_proj/pack2/mod2.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Projects/baka_proj/pack2/mod2.py", line 1, in <module>
    from ..pack1.mod1 import some_vars_to_import
SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import
```

The project has such a structure:

```
proj_root
    __init__.py (empty)
    package1
        mod1.py (here is a variable some_vars_to_import)
        __init__.py (empty)
    package2
        mod2.py (here I try to import by relative path)
        __init__.py (empty)
```

In `mod2.py` I try to import a variable from `mod1.py`:

```
from ..pack1.mod1 import some_vars_to_import
```

And it fails.

Can you tell me, what's wrong with my code?

P.S. https://www.sendspace.com/file/zwmx0v -- here is the project.

Comment: Does every directory have `__init__.py` in it?

Comment: `__init__.py`? Yes, it has. Also, I uploaded it to SendSpace: https://www.sendspace.com/file/zwmx0v

Comment: Does `proj_root` had `__init__.py`?

Comment: Please show the `__init__.py`s in your tree, otherwise it is incomplete.

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/7BMfS — here is a screenshot of my project dir. The link to the archive with the project is attached to the post too.

Comment: @Felix Don't upload images, just include the relevant files (including necessary content) in your question. That way the question will be useful for future readers even if the links go stale.

Comment: See the Q&A I've linked.  It is not actually about relative imports, but the cause of your problem (and the solution) is identical.